# Grails database migration fails with LiquibaseException

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

I'm using the Grails [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).

This is my configuration:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = 'changelog.groovy'
```

When I start my app I get this exception:

```
| Error 2013-08-20 08:55:47,356 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports c
Message: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports c
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports c
->>   61 | getParser in liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    623 | listUnrunChangeSets in liquibase.Liquibase
|     67 | doCall .  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner$_autoRun_closure1
|    132 | executeInSession in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     56 | autoRun . in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner
|     96 | doCall    in DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the `updateOnStartFileNames` property takes an Array, not a String, so the configuration should be

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
```

The plugin iterates over this list executing each in turn, but when given a String it iterates over each character and executes it. Liquibase then throws the exception because it doesn't recognise the suffix of the first letter, in this case, 'c'.